# Does a quarantine virus in the Antivirus Program still exist in system 32 or will be executable in the future?

Tags: windows-7, windows, virus, anti-virus, malware

Nowadays, the virus are so intelligent, they also can create a fake antivirus service program which same name as our antivirus name. The malicious script also create some other fake program which same name like a normal program such as Fake 360 Total Security service program, Fake AlilM malware, Fake KV player malware, Fake QQPROTECT malware. etc. How to detect and remove those fake program if antivirus can't detect them?

Recently, I had scanning all the virus, malware and suspicious software with an Antivirus program. The antivirus program send them all to the quarantine file. Do I need to delete all of these malware in the quarantine file or just quarantine them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: So what’s your actual question? The first paragraph? Or the second paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

There are many practices that can be applied:

1. Have some anti-malware monitoring - that will detect many of them
2. Give users user accounts, not administrator accounts - that will prevent many viruses from obtaining sufficient access.
3. Have a system to check CRC on important .exe files. You can even extend this to get alerts when an .exe changes.
4. Tech users not to click everything they see.